# svn cleanup externals property

Tags: svn, version-control

I need to completely delete external property, after both folder and reference were deleted.

The folders are as follow:

project/folder/subfolder
project/subfolder

when updating I get:

```
 W200000 Error handling externals definition for  project/folder/subfolder
 W210002 Unable to connect to repository at URL svn+ssh://.../project/subfolder
```

Although none of these 2 exist.

running the following in the root directory

```
 svn propedit svn:externals .
```

returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the svn:external on a subfolder of your main project? Run

```
svn propget svn:externals --depth infinity`
```

To see if there are any unwanted properties. Normally, after you remove an externals property, you're best to commit the change and clean up unversioned files before performing another update.